# Why are ARFaceAnchor and ARImageAnchor the only anchor types which are conforming to protocol ARTrackable?

Tags: ios, arkit

In the documentation of the protocol ARTrackable (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/artrackable), it says that Conforming Types are: ARFaceAnchor, ARImageAnchor.

Is there a specific reason why these are the only two anchor types conforming to the protocol? Why aren't ARAnchor, ARObjectAnchor and ARPlaneAnchor conforming to ARTrackable?

Answer (score 2):

ARKit is not currently designed to track moving things like people.  I needs fixed surfaces like walls and tables to know where it is.  The reason that 2D images and faces are an exception is that images can be cheaply detected and tracked by analyzing the frame buffer, while faces get help from the 3D forward illuminated IR camera in faceID as well as the build in neural engine chip to track them in real time.  There is no such hardware support for pre scanned 3d objects and thats likely why they are not trackable in real time.